# Android custom view ignoring `android:enabled` in XML?

Tags: android, view

I'm setting `android:enabled="false"` on a custom view, but it doesn't appear to be having any effect on the `isEnabled()` property.

Here's a simple test case:

```
public class TestView extends View {

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        p.setTextSize(ViewUtils.dpToPx(this, 10));
        canvas.drawText("Enabled = " + (isEnabled() ? "true" : "false"),
                getWidth() / 2,
                getHeight() / 2,
                p);
    }
}
```

And the corresponding XML:

```
<com.example.TestView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"/>
```

The output view looks like this:

[image: output]

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: android:enabled is not referenced as an attribute of view in the doc

Comment: Ah, you're right. Post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `android:enabled` is not an attribute of `View`, as it is not in the documentation.

I don't think there is a way to modify the return value of `isEnabled()` via the XML layout file. (Unless defining custom attributes for a custom view)

Comment: @user3452758: if your edit suggestion is correct, please post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
app:enabled="@{false}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer is late

1. declare in `declare-styleable`

```
  <attr name="android:enabled" format="boolean"/>
```

2. get arr form `TypedArray`

```
isEnabled = typeArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.CunstomView_android_enabled, true)
```

3. then like this

```
<CustomView
  ...
  android:enabled="false"
/>
```